# Overriding Resources

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Eclipse project that uses Gradle for building from command line.
There's a separate resources folder that contains app icon that should be used for a release build.
Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = isRelease() ? ['res', 'res-release'] : ['res']
    }
}
```

Gradle refuses to override the icon:

```
Execution failed for task ':myapp:mergeApphanceDebugResources'.
> /myapp/res-release/drawable-xhdpi/app_icon.png: Error: Duplicate resources: /myapp/res-release/drawable-xhdpi/app_icon.png:drawable-xhdpi/app_icon, /myapp/res/drawable-xhdpi/app_icon.png:drawable-xhdpi/app_icon
```

Is there a way to tell Gradle to overwrite on conflict?

EDIT: I'd like to keep the default Eclipse project structure (i.e. without main/java).

Comment: Why are you not using `debug` and `release` build types for this?

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe I should. Could you please advice how to solve the problem using different build types? (still should be able to get the 'debug' build when build from Eclipse)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is additional in res-release?

Comment: @EugenMartynov for now, just to have different app icons for 'release' & 'debug' builds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark's answer is the right one, but since you commented about Eclipse support in the other answer, I'll create a new answer.

As Mark said, use `src/release/res` (or debug) to put your release only icons. They will automatically override the ones in `src/main/res`

Now if you want to keep supporting Eclipse, just relocate the release sourceset the same way you relocate the main sourceset:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
        release {
            res.srcDirs = ['res-release']
        }
    }
}
```

All build types (by default you have `debug` and `release`), as well as all your flavors (no flavors by default), automatically create sourceSets with default values of `src/<name>/[java|res|...]`. All of those sourceSets can be reconfigured through the DSL to relocate folders around.

Answer (score 4):

Step #1: Put your production icon in `src/main/res/drawable-XXXX/icon.png`, for all necessary values of XXXX, and substituting in what you want for `icon.png`.

Step #2: Put your debug icon in `src/debug/res/drawable-XXXX/icon.png`, for all necessary values of XXXX, and for the same name as you used step #1.

Step #3: There is no step #3. Your `debug` source set's version of the icon should replace the `main` source set's version of the icon at build time.

Answer (score 3):

From comments you just want to have different icons. As Mark suggested it is easy to achieve with flavours. Let me call them `develop` and `production` flavours.

So `build.gradle`:

```
...
android {
    productFlavours {
        develop {
            debuggable true
            packageSuffix ".dev"
        }

        production {
            debuggable false
        }
    }
}
...
```

Project structure:

```
src
-main
 -java
 -res
  -icon.png
-production
 -res
  -icon.png
```

To build apks accordingly:

```
.gradlew assembleDevelop
.gradlew assembleProduction
```

Comment: I'd just go with the stock `debug` and `release` ones, rather than inventing two new build types.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I had not idea that `debug` and `release` are just same configurations as custom in `productFlavours`. If so the amount of text in `build.gradle` will be much less. I will try

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that you were creating product flavors. Since the question is about debug and release builds, I would use the `debug` and `release` build types.

Comment: Thanks. Thing is, this way I'm forced to switch to maven-ish project structure and can't keep the POAEP (plain old Android Eclipse project ;))?

Comment: In this case - write own task to override default icon and hook it into build. I will add new answer tomorrow :)

Comment: That's what I'm doing now (and then calling `git checkout` to revert the change) but thought there could be a better way.

Comment: No needs to write something specific. Xavier's answer is minimalistic and wouldn't make troubles with VCS bus